# Field 'm_name' is uninitialized when used here

Tags: c++, vector, constructor

I am new to the C++ world and I try to implement a simple **exercise** that was given to me:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>

class Student {
public:
explicit Student(const char *name) : m_name(strcpy(/*here*/m_name,name)) , m_scores(0){}
Student() : m_name(strdup("No Name")) , m_scores(0){}


private:
std::vector<double> m_scores;
char *m_name {nullptr};
};
```

I get the following error :
Field 'm_name' is uninitialized when used here.

also, can I set my private data member as std::vector m_name because I have tried it and it also got an error

thanks

Comment: Hint: why do you use `strdup()` in the other ctor?

Comment: You'll want a destructor too.

Comment: `m_name` is a null pointer. Don't use it as the target of `strcpy`; it has no memory to copy to.

Comment: If you're new, you should be using `std::string`.  C legacy routines is not a good way for a beginner to learn C++.

Comment: *"is uninitialized when used here."* -- where precisely is "here"? Which line, and which character in the line? (If my guess is correct, `m_name` appears twice in that line, but only one appearance is the source of the complaint.) Why do you believe `m_name` is initialized at that point?

Comment: Does your teacher insist on you using `char*` and `strcpy`?

Comment: create a Student class as follows:
The class will hold a dynamically allocated array of double representing the student’s scores.
The class will hold a dynamically allocated array of char representing the student’s name.
It will expose the follwing API:
Student(const char * name) -> construct the student with that name and an empty list of scores
Student() -> same but the name is “No Name”

Comment: If you are required to use a dynamically allocated array, you should already know that a pointer is not one. In order to copy a string to an array, you need to have an array.

Comment: Do you want to put an array of characters into a single character?

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer I have needed to alloc new buffer I was trying to strcpy to nullptr which caused to program to run- time crash

```
Student::Student(const char *name) {
m_name = new char[strlen(name)+1];
my_assert(m_name,"alloc failed"); // my custom assertfunction
strcpy(m_name,name);
}
```

Comment: This question/answer combo is unhelpful in the general case as the question and answer both are specific to just this code and do not explain anything about variable initialization. As well, the question consists of only an error message and is not actually a question.